# Ruby parent object gain access to child attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance

So I am wondering if there is a better way of doing this. I have a parent class that has three 1 to 1 relationships, children.

```
class Parent
  has_one :child_one
  has_one :child_two
  has_one :child_three
...
end
```

Then within each child object I state `belongs_to :parent`, now ChildOne has `attribute1`, `attribute2`, `...`, `attribute30` etc.

I am using a gem that uses yaml to build calculations, but it can only access the table or model of the Parent class. It means that all the attributes i need from the ChildOne class  I'll  have to pull like this

```
def calculation_one
  cal_one = self.child_one.attribute1
end
```

and onward. This would mean that I would have a model that's freakin fat just linking children attributes. Is there a better way of doing this?

**Update**

What i am looking for is a way to basically `attr_accessor` a subclass?

```
class Parent
  attr_accessor :child_one, :attribute1
end

person = Parent.new
person.attribute1 = "awesome"
person.attribute1 # => "awesome"
```

Comment: Do you want to access child elements from parent object ?

Comment: Yeah to be able to access `attribute1` from `Parent` class without having to create a method to access it. because then ill need to write out close to 90 methods just to be able to access child attributes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the `Delegate` module in rails : you can call `delegate` to let a related model respond to a method call like that :

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :child_one
  delegate :attribute1, to: :child_one
end
```

Full documentation : http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate

Comment: dude! dude!!! you rock my socks you seriously saved me a lot of time right here. LEGENDARY high five Zapow!!